# How do i add a shadow in react native android < 5.0 versions is there any ways?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Can we add a shadow in react native with android versions < 5.0, I find there's an issue raised but is there any other option to add shadow in there?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about drop shadows. 
As far as i know there is yet no way of adding shadows on android without writing custom code or using a library.. i recommend this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow. Be aware that although it works on iOS its still recommended to use the native shadow methods

Comment: Can you breif it how to apply it , by steps that will be helpful if you dont mind ?

Comment: I did npm install shadow

Comment: @Santhoshs all the steps are stated quite simple in the npm page I mentioned.. apart from what it's written on their page, it's only customization  of the look and feel. 
Did you follow their "how to use it" procedure? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow#how-to-use-it

Comment: yes I am on the steps now , i will update soon whether it is working or nt !

Comment: Hey @Santhoshs any progress with the library? Did it work out for you?

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, and I am not sure whether I have tried it perfectly but I tried it .. it didn't work !!

Comment: It would be great if anyone has done it with tat and represent as demo.